# Containerized Rails application cannot find some libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mariadb, bundler, alpine-linux

I have a Rails app recently upgraded to 6.1 in an alpine 14 container with ruby 3.0.1 with all required gems compiled and installed, but it won't start:

`LoadError: Error loading shared library libmariadb.so.3: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so) - /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so`

The full error text:

```
site                     | LoadError: Error loading shared library libmariadb.so.3: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so) - /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2.rb:36:in `<main>'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
site                     | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
site                     | /app/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
site                     | /app/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
site                     | /app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
site                     | /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
site                     | /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
site                     | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
site                     | rake aborted!
```

I don't know exactly what it's trying to load and from where.

I have libmariadb.so.3 (from mariadb-connector-c) installed into /usr/lib and also linked to /usr/local/lib.

/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so is also there.

I am not deleting any packages or gems before starting up and there were no errors during bundle installation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, I switched to a centos image until they fix the alpine packages

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to get around this by

```
apk add mariadb-dev
```

Hopefully that helps someone else!